# Simplifying large exponents in modular arithmetic like $1007$ in $4^{1007} \pmod{5}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How would I rigorously prove that $4^{1007} \pmod{5} = 4$ and $4^{1008} \pmod{5} = 1$?

I was simplifying a larger modular arithmetic problem ($2013^{2014} \pmod{5}$) and got it down to $4^{1007} \pmod{5}$ and am wondering if there's a general approach to dealing with large exponents like $1007$.

In general, what approaches are there to simplify large exponents like $1007$ when doing modular arithmetic?

Comment: See also: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To answer the general question, there are two handy ways of simplifying $$a^k \pmod n.$$

### Method 1

We have the property of modulo arithmetic:  If $a \equiv b \pmod n$ and $c \equiv d \pmod n$, then $ac \equiv bd \pmod n$.  This has the corollary:

> If $a \equiv b \pmod n$ then $a^k \equiv b^k \pmod n$ for all $k \geq 1$.

In this case, we see $4 \equiv -1 \pmod 5$.  So $$4^{1007} \equiv (-1)^{1007} \pmod 5.$$  But we know $(-1)^{1007}=-1$ since $1007$ is odd.  So $$4^{1007} \equiv -1 \pmod 5.$$  We can then multiply both sides by $-1$ to show $$4^{1008} \equiv 1 \pmod 5.$$

### Method 2

[Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), which implies that if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $a^{\varphi(n)}=1 \pmod n$, where $\varphi$ is the [Euler phi-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).  This has the consequence:

> If $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then $$a^k \equiv a^{k \text{ mod } \varphi(n)} \pmod n$$ for all $k \geq 1$.

So, in the example, we compute $\varphi(5)=4$ (since $5$ is prime), then we know $$4^{1007} \equiv 4^{1007 \text{ mod } 4} \equiv 4^3 \equiv 4 \pmod 5.$$  We can then multiply by $4$ to show $$4^{1008} \equiv 1 \pmod 5.$$

Comment: In method 2, I can't quite follow the transition from Euler's Theorem to $$a^k \equiv a^{k \text{ mod } \varphi(n)} \pmod n$$ for all $k \geq 1$ . Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Since $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ we know that $a^k \equiv a^k a^{\varphi(n)} = a^{k+\varphi(n)} \pmod n$.  If we do repeatedly, we get $a^k \equiv a^{k+\varphi(n)} \equiv a^{k+2\varphi(n)} \equiv \cdots \pmod n$.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, some common sense can help a lot and even without Fermat's theorem:

$$4=-1\pmod 5\implies\begin{align*} 4^{1007}&=(-1)^{1007}=-1=4\pmod 5\;,\\{}\\
\;\;4^{1008}&=(-1)^{1008}=1\pmod 5\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

Another method for this is repeated squaring.

Take $n^d \mod b$ then

find all $a^{2^k} \mod b$ for all $2^k <= d$  where $d$ is $n^d$

$$\begin{align}
4^2 &= 16 = 1 \\
4^4 &= (4^2)^2 = 1^2 \\
4^8 &= (4^4)^2 = 1^2 \\
&... \\
4^{512} &= 1 \\
\end{align}$$

for $4^{1007}$ we have:

$$\begin{align}
4^{1007} 
  &= 4^{512} * 4^{256} * 4^{128} * 4^{64} * 4^{32} * 4^8 * 4^4 * 4^2 * 4  \\
  &= 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 4 \mod 5 \\
  &= 4 \mod 5  
\end{align}$$

and for $4^{1008}$ we have:

$$\begin{align}
4^{1008}
  &= 4^{512} * 4^{256} * 4^{128} * 4^{64} * 4^{32} * 4^{16} \\
  &= 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 \\
  &= 1 \mod 5 \\
\end{align}$$

Further details:
http://www.tricki.org/article/To_work_out_powers_mod_n_use_repeated_squaring

Answer (score 2):

Use Fermat's Theorem which tells that if $p$ is a prime and $gcd(a,p)=1$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1(\mod~p)$.

For further elaboration on Fermat's Theorem see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html or any standard text in Number Theory.

Comment: How would I use Fermat's Theorem in $4^{1007} \pmod{5}$ when the only factors of $1007$ are $19$ and $53$, neither of which are $p - 1 = 5 - 1 = 4$?

Comment: $4^4\equiv1(mod~5)\Rightarrow(4^4)^{251}\equiv1^{251}(mod~5)\Rightarrow4^{1007} \equiv 4^3 \equiv 4(mod~5)$