# Modulus function, finding $2^{2014} \mod 11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any way I can compute $2^{2014} \mod 11$?

I tried squaring the terms every time, but can't seem to get to $2014$.

Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard about [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)?

Comment: Unfortunately no, my professor hasn't taught that yet :(

Comment: Well, that's just evil, telling you to calculate this without giving you the theorem that helps you. At any rate, the answers below tell you how to use the theorem in this specific case.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491576/simplifying-large-exponents-in-modular-arithmetic-like-1007-in-41007-pmod

Comment: @Arthur I included my answer *without* Fermat's Little Theorem, making use of binary and consecutive squaring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2^{10}\equiv 1 \mod 11$$

$$2^{2014} \equiv 2^{2010+4} \equiv 2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 5 \mod 11$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$2^5 \equiv -1 \pmod{11} $$ $$\implies (2^5)^{402} \equiv (-1)^{402} \pmod{11} $$ $$\implies 2^{2010}\cdot 2^4 \equiv 1\cdot 2^4 \pmod{11} $$
$$\implies 2^{2014} \equiv 16 \pmod{11}$$ $$\implies \boxed{2^{2014} \equiv 5 \pmod{11} }$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use Fermat's little theorem, then just note that $2014 = 1024 + 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2$ so

$2^{2014}\ =\ 2^{1024 + 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2}\ =\ 2^{1024}\cdot2^{512}\cdot2^{256}\cdot2^{128}\cdot2^{64}\cdot2^{16}\cdot2^{8}\cdot2^{4}\cdot2^{2}$

And each one of those factors can be computed by consecutive squaring.